# How to implement multi-output losses using the same label in TensorFlow 2.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

Using Keras in TensorFlow 2.x, I have a model that predicts something on multiple scales.

However, independent of the scale, the predicted content is the same and thus shares the same label that is fed from a `tf.data.Dataset` to `model.fit()`.

As a consequence, the output of the model is a list of multiple tensors, while the label from the `tf.data.Dataset` is a single tensor. This results in the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected.
```

How can I make the model aware of the repetition of the label?

Ideally, I don't want to replicate the label inside the `tf.data.Dataset` (unless there is a way to tile my label without consuming more memory).